# Unity Cursor missing, can't click buttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a Game right now, I have a problem with the main menu. When I press ESC, the menu opens and the time freezes. The cursor is then visible. But I can still look around, while the menu is on the screen. And if I click a button, for example the resume button, nothing happens.

Comment: So the cursor is visible but the buttons don't do anything?

Answer (score 0):

If the buttons don't do anything, make sure to asign a task for each button, for example, if you want to pause the game when the player press the pause button, make sure that the pause button has the task of pausing the game asigned to it.

I think that your problem is with the Event System of your scene, the Canvas needs an event system to work properly, if you delete it or change something in the event system, the Canvas will not work.

The Event System is created automatically when you add a canvas into your scene, make sure it looks like that:[image]

Comment: The EventSystem looks exactly the same. But yep I changed the GameObject from None to my Pause Menu. This at least made the cursor appear when i activate the pause menu.